# When i do g++ -lpthread sample.cpp it gives me a error of undefined reference to `pthread_join'

Tags: c++, g++, pthreads

However when i type in g++ sample.cpp -o sample -lpthread it works normally. I would do that however my professor is very strict on the way i compile.

Comment: I think this solves your problem. Note that it is not always necessarily true to have linker before/after your source file as it varies from projects to projects. You should clarify with your prof. What happens is your sample.cpp depends on -pthread and you should link it after your cpp file, not before. https://stackoverflow.com/a/409402/8532468

Comment: so i was correct on using g++ sample.cpp -o sample -lpthread? My professor is very strict so what should i do? Thanks!

Comment: Think you might have misunderstood your professor, or he is wrong. You should clarify with him. The standard for GNU compilers is to link libraries after the source file that depends on those libraries. This is a very good and comprehensive guide on linking, applies to gcc, g++ compilers https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking

Comment: Maybe, it would be better to compile and link in two separate steps.